# Check string for XXNNNN

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to validate a string using Regex to check that string is:

```
XXNNNN
```

where X is an alphabet and N is a number.

Comment: Any effort so far? How about `^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}$`?

Comment: The answer to your question is: **Yes**, it is.

Comment: You should show us the efforts you made and point where you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex.

```
^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{4}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
[A-Za-z]{2}              any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
                         (2 times)
\d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this variant](http://regex101.com/r/zM9wX9/1) to catch all occurences in a text: `\b\w{2}\d{4}\b`

This adds the word boundary notation in order to avoid picking. You may prefer Avinash `^` and `$`, depends on what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
bool valid = str.Length == 6 
          && str.Remove(2).All(Char.IsLetter) && str.Substring(2).All(Char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: You could have used `Take` and `Skip`, it would have been Linq-ier ;)

Comment: @samy: yes, that would work also, but string methods are more efficient.